# How do I use setblock with a coloured sign?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to create a 1 command block house for a datapack function (as I'm learning how to create datapacks) and I want a sign in the basement of my house however I can't get the sign to be coloured at all. I'm able to give myself a custom sign:

```
/give @p oak_sign{BlockEntityTag:{Text1:"{\"text\":\"Push For\",\"color\":\"dark_red\"}",Text2:"{\"text\":\"a\"}",Text3:"{\"text\":\"b\"}",Text4:"{\"text\":\"c\"}"}}
```

However when I try to put the entitytag into a `/setblock` command it doesn't work and just creates a blank sign. This is the command I'm using to test.

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ oak_sign{BlockEntityTag:{Text1:"{\"text\":\"Push For\",\"color\":\"dark_red\"}",Text2:"{\"text\":\"a\"}",Text3:"{\"text\":\"b\"}",Text4:"{\"text\":\"c\"}"}}
```

Is there a different method for when I use `/setblock`?

Edit for anyone who might have the same problem: When setting block you don't need the "BlockEntityTag". You can just use:

{Text1:"{\"text\":\"Push For\",\"color\":\"dark_red\"}",Text2:"{\"text\":\"a\"}",Text3:"{\"text\":\"b\"}",Text4:"{\"text\":\"c\"}"}

(Make sure to delete the extra } on the end of the command.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can I only receive a special loot table from a chest using /give and not /summon?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/312597/why-can-i-only-receive-a-special-loot-table-from-a-chest-using-give-and-not-su)

Comment: While the underlying issue is the same, the context where it occurs is substantially different, especially for new players. As such, I'm calling "no duplicate".